# What are best practices for handling ids in web services?

Tags: database, web-services, database-design, architecture

We have two separate systems communicating via a web service.  Call them front-end and back-end.  A lot of the processing involves updating lists in the back-end.  For example, the front-end needs to update a specific person.  Currently, we are designing the back-end where we are making the decision on what the interface should be.  We will need the actual database ids to update the underlying database, but we also see where propagating database ids to our consumers could be a bad idea.

What are some alternatives in forcing the clients (i.e. front-end) to have to send ids back into the web service to update a particular entity?  The other reason we are trying to avoid ids is the front-end often saves these changes to be sent at a later date.  This would require the front-ends to save our ids in their system, which also seems like a bad idea.

We have considered the following:

1) Send database ids back to front-end; they would have to send these back to process the change

2) Send hashed ids (based off of database ids) back to the front-end; they would have to send these back to process the change.

3)  Do not force the clients to send ids at all but have them send the original entity and new entity and "match" to our entity in the database.  Their original entity would have to match our saved entity.  We would also have to define what constitutes a match between our entity and their new entity.

Comment: yipes - it feels like 1 and 2 are essentially the same.  also 3 - when you 'define' what makes a match - that will almost certainly be the id that is the key.. (or uglier - find alternate keys for everything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reasonable way for front-end would be to someway identify persons in DB.

Matching the full entity is unreliable and isn't obvious; for returning hashed ID to front-end you need to receive not-hashed ID from front-end first, or perform some revertible "hashing" (more like "encrypting") under IDs, so anyway there would be some person identifier.

IMHO it does not matter whether it will be a database ID or some piece of data (encrypted database ID) from which the ID could be extracted. Why do you think that consumers knowing the database ID would be a bad idea? I don't see any problem as long as every person belongs to a single consumer.

If there is many-to-many relation between persons (objects in DB) and consumers, then you may "encrypt" (in the broad sense) the object id so that the encryption will be consumer-dependent. For example, in communication with consumer you can use the ID of the link (between object and consumer) entry in DB.

If sending IDs to consumers seems to be the bad idea for you because of the possibility of consumer enumerating all the IDs one-by-one, you can avoid this problem by using GUIDs instead of an integer auto-incremented IDs.

PS: As for your comment, consider using e.g. GUID as an object ID. The ID is the part of data, not the part of schema, so it will be preserved when migrating between databases. Such the ID won't contain sensitive information as well, so it is perfectly safe to reveal the ID to consumer (or someone else). If you want to prevent creation of two different persons with the same SSNs, just add an `UNIQUE` key on your SSN field, but do not use SSN as the part of ID, as such approach has many serious disadvantages, with inability to reveal the ID being the least of them.

Comment: The main reason we have been hesitant on sending the database ids is it somewhat couples the two systems together.  If we decided to change the database, this could impact the front-ends.  In addition, it is conceivable that the ids could contain some sensitive information if they were for example natural keys (based off of ssn for example).  We are trying to be pragmatic but also follow best practices.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: 1) Changing the database should not change IDs. 2) IDs should not be natural keys; what if, for some reason, SSN will change (e.g. customer entered the wrong SSN by mistake), or you'll need to support customers from other countries? You're looking at the problem from the wrong end; first you implement wrong data structure (with IDs containing sensitive information and subjected to change with DB reworking), and then you're trying to implement some way to work with objects without knowing their IDs.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view the id of a record does not convey any sensitive information to anyone.
As a result there is no problem transmitting database ids to front-end (and in general).
The only concern would be related to database consistency issues, but I can not see any.
Additionally from performance it is much better, since you don't need to query the database on attributes to find the database id.

Additionally if you send a hash of the id you can not extract the id from the hash.
You would have to find an id in the database that matches the hash and that is not good IMO

So:

> we also see where propagating database ids to our consumers could be a
>   bad idea.

I don't see it. If you could explain why you think is a bad idea, may be there would be a discussion.

Comment: See my comments below to the other answer.  My main arguments would be the coupling of the systems and possible security issue if the database ids were using natural keys.

Comment: 1)If the database is an SSN, that could be perhaps an issue.But is it?Or are we talking theoritically?2)Concerning the coupling:If you change the database, the data will not be thrown away.Your schema would be migrated to the new database.So what concerns you?

Comment: 1) We are talking in theory.  2)  Yes, the schema could change, but again it would be nice to have the schema and database evolve independent.  Even from a non-theoretical point of view, this is pretty common they are modeled differently.  The database is normalized differently than the actual schema.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I understand your concerns.I have seen the usage of the database id in practice and actually it solves quite a lot of problems (from the implementation side).If I may, I would suggest you to see what requirements you have and apply those.To investigate generally best practices/approaches for problems not applied to your case is a common bad path IMHO.It leads to build a framework instead of a simple class.It increases development time, debugging time and maintaince and usually their is no justification in retrospect.